# Pie chart creating from JSON Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, infragistics

I am new in PHP and JavaScript, i need to create a pie chart using JSON data  which will be get from the URL. The JSON data is :

```
[
  {"Domain":"Artificial Intelligence","Count":"46"}, 
  {"Domain":"Data Architecture","Count":"21"}, 
  {"Domain":"Data Science","Count":"50"}, 
]
```

The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"> 
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn- na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.dv.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
 # Reading JSN Data from URLS
 $jsn_data =    
 file_get_contents("http://localhost:9080/Badges/reporting/badge_json.php");
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $("#chart").igPieChart({
            width: "435px",
            height: "435px",
            dataSource: result, 
            dataValue: "count",
            dataLabel: "Domain",
            labelsPosition: "bestFit"
        });

      });
    <script>

 </body>
 s</html>
```

But this code does not work. please tell me how do this ?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What do you get in $jsn_data?  Try wrapping your url using `urlencode`  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work". Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Did you check the generated page to make sure your php is correct? Is everything good but the chart doesn't show up?

Comment: i need to create a pi chart using JSON data from URL..I tried many times..but didn't get any result...chart doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

dataLabel: "Badge_SubDomain" doesn't exist in your data source.

Maybe try something like ...

```
   $("#chart").igPieChart({
            width: "435px",
            height: "435px",
            dataSource: result, 
            dataValue: "count",
            dataLabel: "Domain",
            labelsPosition: "bestFit"
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix these:

1. JSON property **Count** is a *string*, not an *integer*
2. The code is broken, it needs to be fixed
3. The variable **result** is not defined anywhere in the `<script>` tag
4. The JavaScript snippet is inside `<?php/>` tag, move it outside

---

here's the fixed code:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
        <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.dv.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({type:"GET", url: "badge_json.php", success: function(data) {
                $("#chart").igPieChart({
                    width: "435px",
                    height: "435px",
                    dataSource: data, 
                    dataValue: "Count",
                    dataLabel: "Domain",
                    labelsPosition: "bestFit"
                });
            }});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and **badge_json.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // your data goes here
    $data = array(
        ['Domain' => 'Artificial Intelligence', 'Count' => 46],
        ['Domain' => 'Data Architecture', 'Count' => 21],
        ['Domain' => 'Data Science', 'Count' => 50]
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```