# display pi chart using json data from URL

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am new in PHP and Javascript. i need to create pi chart from JSON which should be read from URL.

I tried to create pi chart to directly given json data and it works. 
My code is given below :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"> 
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.1/latest/js/infragistics.dv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
     #chart { position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
}   
</style>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var data = [
            { "Badge_SubDomain": "Data Architecture", "count": "1333"},
            { "Badge_SubDomain": "Data Integration", "count": "849"},
            { "Badge_SubDomain": "Data Platform", "count": "250"},
                 ];

        $("#chart").igPieChart({
            width: "435px",
            height: "435px",
            dataSource: data, 
            dataValue: "count",
            dataLabel: "Badge_SubDomain",
            labelsPosition: "bestFit" });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data from the URL is :-

```
[{  
    "Domain":"Artificial Intelligence",
    "Count":"46"
}, {  
    "Domain":"Data Architecture",
    "Count":"21"
}, {  
    "Domain":"Data Science",
    "Count":"50"
}]
```

I need to read data from URL instead of direct giving value. The 'Count' in JSON data is in string format and it needs to change float format for plotting pi chart. How can i change code for it?

Comment: A π-Chart or a Pie-Chart?

Comment: "I need to read data from URL instead of direct giving value"  Okay, so what have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pie chart creating from JSON Data in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465963/pie-chart-creating-from-json-data-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted the same question twice, but you need to delete at least one of them

Answer (score -1):

```
$.get("url", function(data, status){
```

> var data = [
>           {"Domain":"Artificial Intelligence","Count":"46"}, 
>           {"Domain":"Data Architecture","Count":"21"}, 
>           {"Domain":"Data Science","Count":"50"}, 
>           ]

```
finalArray = data.map(data => parseFloat(data.Count));
```

});
Result = [46, 21, 50]

Comment: The user posted the same question twice. I'd post your answer on the first one, this one will almost certainly be closed/deleted. See the dupe link in the comment on the question.